# find a quadratic polynomial p ( x ) and a number n such that p ( x ) and a number $n \pmod n $ has at least 2015 roots?

Tags: roots, quadratics

I understand what the question is asking for, but I don't know how to prove my answer.  Let's say I took an  equation of the form: $x^2+ 6x+ 8 \equiv0 \pmod {15}$.  The first four roots are $1,8,11,13\dots$ and this can continue infinitely.  How do  I prove that this quadratic polynomial has at least $2015$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Show that if $n$ is the product of $k$ distinct primes, then the congruence $x^2-1\equiv 0\pmod{n}$ has $2^k$ solutions.

If you want a simpler but much less interesting approach, use the congruence $x^2\equiv 0\pmod{2^k}$ where $k$ is large.

**Remark:** It is not clearly stated, but I believe that you are expected to consider two solutions $x$ and $x'$ which are congruent modulo $n$ as the **same** solution. So in your example the *only* roots (up to congruence modulo $15$) are the ones you gave.

Comment: Yes sorry, my Professor wasn't very clear in the homework.  I do believe however that that is the case.  Would this then affect my solution?

Comment: The congruence $x^2\equiv 0\pmod 2$ has "infinitely many" solutions, $0, \pm 2,\pm 4,\pm 6, \dots$. But in essence they  are one solution. I cannot guess what your professor intended. If this is allowed the problem is very easy. If $x$ and $x'$ which are congruent mod $n$ are considered to be the same solution, the problem becomes harder, and is dealt with in my answer.  For example (easiest) the congruence $x^2\equiv 0\pmod{2^{5000}}$ has more than $2015$ incongruent solutions.